# Why does mousemove event only trigger once and trigger again only when cursor leaves window and returns?

Tags: jquery, dom-events

I am trying to use a jQuery `mousemove` event, but the `mousemove` event only triggers one time. The event won't trigger again until I move the cursor outside of the page window and then move the cursor back into the window.

I tried using both normal Javascript as well as jQuery, but the same issue occurs. When I try this code on a test web page, it works as expected. I am having this issue with a legacy application that uses Primefaces and a frameset with frames. Looking to know if anyone knows what would typically cause this behavior.

jQuery:

```
var counter = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        counter = counter + 1;
    console.log(counter);
    });
```

Javascript:

```
var counter = 0;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function() { 
        counter = counter + 1;
    console.log(counter);
}, false);
```

I expect the counter to keep counting when I move the mouse around, but it only counts once and then again after moving the mouse out of the window and back into the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach the event to a DOM element like a div (container)

```
<script>
$( "div" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  //handle event here
});
</script>
```